# Linux Chromebook

Tags: linux, chromebook

Update: I put back into developer mode and got the apk's installed needed; but still will try to install linux

I had this same thing with a previous chromebook but can't remember the fix / step used

Bear with me - am not linux fluent at all

Lenovo Ideapad 3

Installed Linux, open terminal and instead of username at command line it says `crosh`; how do I get it to the right user and where I can install apps?

It definitely does not recognize the command: `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y` and gives an error message.

I think the command line needs to say our username or penguin or we have to be in penguin

Have used the Linux terminal to install apps on previous chromebook -just been a while.

Screenshot of terminal when it opens:

[image: scrot]

Comment: Hey thanks, that does not work either, was about to post that screenshot, it says: ERROR - ERROR: unknown command: shell

Comment: SHould we put it in developer mode? That is not required anymore (the instructions you sent are from 2014; nowadays dev mode not required to run linux is all we have read)

Comment: Thanks Peregrino69- bear with me I have an acquired TBI and mild visual disability and the specifics of posting you requested not doable for me; just need to do the easiest. Even being on here is difficult. The only reason am here is no one to help and use laptop as a phone as can't use a smartphone touchscreen
Have to reinstall linux, even though it was installed it somehow got turned off

Comment: So will post again in six hours that's how long it takes to do the install ((&^*% swear word)

Comment: ok thankyou....